# Parse.com Open Push Url From Wordpress PostID

Tags: php, android, json, wordpress, parse-platform

I'm using a plugin for wordpress called Simple Parse Push Service
https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-parse-push-service/

It sends a push notification to parse.com which is then sent to my android app.
And I want to be able to open the post url from the push being sent.

In the push details on parse.com I get

```
FULL TARGET
{ }

FULL DATA
{ "alert": "Check this out", "badge": "", "post_id": 9953, "sound": "" }
```

From what I understand the wordpress plugin is sending the postID via json to parse.com

And if I can pass this postID with a url **http://tld.com/?p="post_id"** to my android app I should be able to get the push notification to open the url of my post.

I'm seeing various documentation online about how to set parse.com broadcastReceiver but I don't see anything close to what I'm trying to get done and I'm not sure how I should go about doing this.

Would appreciate any help I can get on this.